# Why would React-Navigation documentation not include some of the most important props and functionalities?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-native-screens

After playing around with React-Navigation's Native Stack **headerSearchBarOptions** to render a native search bar on iOS in my React-Native project, I wanted to implement search functionality. However, I just couldn't figure out how to apply logic *whenever a user hits the **search** button on their mobile keyboard*. In the documentation, there was no option/property that would allow me to call an API when the user presses the **search** button on their keyboard. There are only **onBlur, onCancelButtonPress,** and **onChangeText**, none of which would help me.

So, I spent a considerable amount of time Googling (nothing came up) and playing around with React Native's **Keyboard** event listeners to achieve the *onPressSearch* functionality. To my surprise, when I was writing *onSearch* in VSCode, there was a suggestion of the **onSearchButtonPress** option in the **headerSearchBarOptions**, and it worked just like I expected.

If the React-Navigation team had included this option in their documentation, I wouldn't have spent a lot of time trying to reinvent the wheel. Why would they not include it in their documentation since it'll be one of the most important options they provide? If I go to **React Native Screens** on GitHub, however, I could see the **onSearchButtonPress** functionality there. Are we as developers expected to assume more options/functionality than what the documentation provides and dig deeper into their repositories on our own, or is it just the React-Navigation team's carelessness?

I tried to implement the onSearchButtonPress functionality on my own when I found it accidentally on VSCode, but it was not in the official documentation.